# Editing UITableViewController's UITableView in stroryboard

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitableview

I've followed this [Parse Tutorial](https://parse.com/tutorials/parse-query-table) to create a custom UITableViewController. I'd like to be able to edit the UITableView in storyboard. I thought somewhere in this tutorial I'd be linking the ViewController to a TableView, but I didn't have too. How can I access this TableView in stroyboard that is linked to this ViewController for UI editing?

Here is the ViewController [code](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/TodoTable/blob/master/ParseStarterProject/MyTableController.m) on GitHub.

Edit: This really has nothing to do with the Parse API. The tableview is not in the storyboard - this is the issue I'm trying to solve. The tutorial instructed me to add this to AppDelegate.m:

```
MyTableViewController *controller = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];

self.window.rootViewController = controller;
```

And this to MyTableViewController.m:

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style

{

self = [super initWithStyle:style];

if (self) {

    // Custom the table

    // The className to query on

    self.className = @"Artists"; 

    // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style

    self.keyToDisplay = @"artistName"; 

    // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled

    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;


    // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled

    self.paginationEnabled = YES;


    // The number of objects to show per page

    self.objectsPerPage = 50;

 }

return self;

}
```

The app is running fine, but all I have in storyboard is a blank View. Do I need to create a TableView and link it to MyTableViewController? I'm guessing I would have to remove that self.window... code from AppDelegate.

Edit: Updated Code:

```
#import "MyTableViewController.h"

@implementation MyTableViewController
@synthesize tableView = _tableView;


#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];


    // Custom the table

    // The className to query on
    self.className = @"Artists";

    // The key of the PFObject to display in the label of the default cell style
    self.keyToDisplay = @"artistName";

    // Whether the built-in pull-to-refresh is enabled
    self.pullToRefreshEnabled = YES;

    // Whether the built-in pagination is enabled
    self.paginationEnabled = YES;

    // The number of objects to show per page
    self.objectsPerPage = 50;




// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
// self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this     view controller.
 self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setTableView:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
// e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:            (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
// Return YES for supported orientations
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - Parse

- (void)objectsDidLoad:(NSError *)error {
[super objectsDidLoad:error];

// This method is called every time objects are loaded from Parse via the PFQuery
}

- (void)objectsWillLoad {
[super objectsWillLoad];

// This method is called before a PFQuery is fired to get more objects
}


// Override to customize what kind of query to perform on the class. The default is to query for
// all objects ordered by createdAt descending.
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.className];

// If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
// and then subsequently do a query against the network.
if ([self.objects count] == 0) {
    // ** There are other caching options in Parse iOS guide
    query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkElseCache;
}

[query orderByDescending:@"tweetInfluence"];

return query;
}
// Override to customize the look of a cell representing an object. The default is to display
// a UITableViewCellStyleDefault style cell with the label being the first key in the object. 
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell
cell.textLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"artistName"];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tweet Influence: %@", [object objectForKey:@"tweetInfluence"]];

return cell;
}
#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[super tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using storyboards, then you should remove

```
MyTableViewController *controller = [[MyTableViewController alloc] init];

self.window.rootViewController = controller;
```

From the AppDelegate. With storyboards, the entry point of the app is controlled on the storyboard itself, represented by the right-facing arrow.

Also, as the code stands now, your app is calling the `init` function on your view controller, not the `initWithStyle` function. You should put the code that is currently in `initWithStyle` in your view controller's `viewDidLoad` function to ensure it will be called.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm still receiving this error: `Couldn't compile connection: <IBCocoaTouchOutletConnection:0x400c42f20  <IBProxyObject: 0x400c4e400> => tableCell => <IBUITableViewCell: 0x400c57660>>`

Comment: You may have accidentally connected a cell from your table view as an IBOutlet instead of the table view itself. Try right clicking on any visible table view cells and making sure they don't have anything set under "Outlets." You can click the X to remove them. Then connect the table to the `tableView` property instead, by ctrl-dragging from some area on it that's not covered by a cell (Or find it in the view hierarchy on the left side of the storyboard screen).